# ASP LinkButton Does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net

The update and Delete buttons in the command fields work fine. The Insert does not work....no errors. Any ideas? Thank you!!

Just to reiterate, the update and delete button do update the database.

Below are three sections, the code, codebehind, and sqldatasource.

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" ShowFooter="True">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="ID">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                 <FooterTemplate>

                                <asp:LinkButton  ID="lbInsert" runat="server" OnClick="lbInsert_Click" CausesValidation="False">INSERT</asp:LinkButton>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ServerName" SortExpression="ServerName">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ServerName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ServerName") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>

                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </FooterTemplate>

            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ServiceName" SortExpression="ServiceName">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ServiceName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ServiceName") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </FooterTemplate>

            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Version" SortExpression="Version">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Version") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Version") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>

                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </FooterTemplate>

            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#F7DFB5" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#A55129" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#FFF7E7" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFF1D4" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#B95C30" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1E5CE" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#93451F" />
    </asp:GridView>



   <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ 
    ConnectionStrings:DBADASHBOARDDBConnectionString %>" DeleteCommand="DELETE 
    FROM [DBADASHTABLE] WHERE [ID] = @ID" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO 
    [DBADASHTABLE] ([ServerName], [ServiceName], [Version]) VALUES (@ServerName, 
    @ServiceName, @Version)" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [DBADASHTABLE]" 
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [DBADASHTABLE] SET [ServerName] = @ServerName, 
    [ServiceName] = @ServiceName, [Version] = @Version WHERE [ID] = @ID">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="ServerName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ServiceName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Version" Type="String" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="ServerName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ServiceName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Version" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

    {
    public class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

      {

    }
    protected void lbInsertClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataSource2.insertparameters["ServerName"].DefaultValue = 
            ((TextBox)GridView2.footerrow.FindControl(TextBox4)).Text;
        SqlDataSource2.insertparameters["ServiceName"].DefaultValue =
            ((TextBox)GridView2.footerrow.FindControl(TextBox5)).Text;
        SqlDataSource2.insertparameters["Version"].DefaultValue =
            ((TextBox)GridView2.footerrow.FindControl(TextBox6)).Text;

        SqlDataSource2.Insert();
       }
       } 
    }

   }
```

Comment: i hope you should change your `OnClick="lbInsert_Click"` to `OnClick="lbInsertClick"`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. When I do that I get the following:

Comment: 'ASP.default_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'lbInsertClick' and no extension method 'lbInsertClick' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.default_aspx' could be found

Comment: Hi, does anyone else have any ideas? Thank you